# Get json object with jquery without using the $.each

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, api, last.fm

- I'm using the recenttracks api from lastFm:

  www.last.fm/api/show?service=278
- I'm fetching the json format with jquery:

  http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=user.getRecentTracks&user=melroymusic&api_key=690e1ed3bc00bc91804cd8f7fe5ed6d4&limit=5&format=json&callback=?

I want to retrieve the status of the first track

```
"@attr":{"nowplaying":"true"}
```

I have this code to retrieve information about each track

```
$.getJSON("http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=user.getRecentTracks&user=melroymusic&api_key=690e1ed3bc00bc91804cd8f7fe5ed6d4&limit=3&format=json&callback=?",

function(data){
    $.each(data.recenttracks.track, function(i,item){
    $("#lastfmMenu").append("<div class='lastfmItem'><div class='lastfmText'>"+item.artist['#text']+"</div>" + "<div class='lastfmDate'>"+item.name+"</div></div>");
    });
});
```

to retrieve the nowplaying status of the first track, logically I would do

```
$.getJSON("http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=user.getRecentTracks&user=melroymusic&api_key=690e1ed3bc00bc91804cd8f7fe5ed6d4&limit=3&format=json&callback=?",

function(data){
    if (data.recenttracks.track[0]['@attr'].nowplaying == true){
        $("#lastfmMenu").append("Now Playing");
    }
    else {
        $("#lastfmMenu").append("Just played");
    }
});
```

doesn't give me any results.

Hope you can help me out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it because nowplaying is a string not a bool, so it should be

```
.nowplaying == "true"?
```

Not at a pc so I can't check.

Answer (score 0):

did you try to parse it first? Try this (untested),

```
function(data){
  **var parsedData = $.parseJSON(data)**
    if (parsedData.recenttracks.track[0]['@attr'].nowplaying == true){
      $("#lastfmMenu").append("Now Playing");
    }
    else {
      $("#lastfmMenu").append("Just played");
    }
});
```

Comment: Actually, even if you parse it, it will still keep it as a string.SO David is correct